# Is Solaris 11.4 beta a text-only distro?

Tags: solaris

Watching a few Youtube videos about installation of Solaris 11.4 beta I got an impression that they get a text mode console login and that's about it. There is no Live CD/USB image on Oracle's site, so I did not try. Did anyone already install 11.4, if you did - does it come with XOrg like 11.3 did?

Comment: At the moment, the 11.4-beta installer is the "Text installer", only. The system may be further configured after installation. Since I'm not using Solaris 11.4-beta with a GUI, I haven't looked to see what the available options for a desktop environment is at the moment. I would be very surprised if a GUI installer did not appear later.

Answer (score 6):

The installer is text only, but after you install the OS you can run "pkg install solaris-desktop" to get Xorg, GNOME 3.24, Firefox, Pidgin, and other packages that were provided by the Live CD/USB images in previous releases.

This is covered in the Solaris 11.4 docs under *[Installing the Oracle Solaris OS](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37838_01/html/E61019/install-groups-1.html)*.